# Event trigger on <option> doesn't work on webkit

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, eventtrigger

I want to add an event trigger on a drop-down `<select>` list. Example ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7cwytnpb/)):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.lorem').click(function() {
        alert('ipsum');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option class="lorem">1</option>
  <option class="lorem">2</option>
</select>
```

With Firefox, when I click on it, it triggers fine. But on webkit (Chrome/Safari etc), it does not work. Why?

Comment: Do you specifically need to add an event listener on the `<option>` elements, or do you just want to listen for input on the `<select>` element?

Comment: Do you specifically want to know why? It's probably a quirk of how click events bubble in each browser. The solution is to use change of the select not click of the options.

Comment: Yes, as stated in my question, with a solution as well.

Comment: Well the solution is covered in the duplicate I've flagged

Comment: @Liam Great, but those answers do not provide an answer *why* this is working on FF and not webkit.

Comment: Aside from `click` not working on `option` elements in all browsers (the reason is simply down to their interpretation of the spec. It's not documented anywhere) it's also bad practice for accessibility reasons. Always use `change`, then the problem is moot.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks!

Comment: Vote to reopen. This question is not a duplicate. The OP is specifically asking **why** the code works with Firefox but not with WebKit, and the linked duplicate does not address that issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this to detect input changes, you can use `.change()`:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $("select").change(function(e) {
    console.log($("select").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option class="lorem">1</option>
  <option class="lorem">2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could instead use a `change` event on your select element and then check where the selected option has the `lorem` class like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    if ($("option:selected", this).hasClass('lorem')) {
      alert('ipsum');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option class="lorem">1</option>
  <option class="lorem">2</option>
  <option class="foo">3</option>
</select>
```